# Razer blade stealth 2016 Caps lock switch off freezes system

Tags: capslock

ive scoured the internet but cant seem to find an answer. Everytime i press caps lock and when i go to switch off caps lock it causes the system to freeze. Running Ubuntu 22.04. i have tried installing sudo apt install openrazer-meta but than get these errors:
python3-numpy : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or
liblapack.so.3
Any help would be appreciated and i am a noob at ubuntu as well.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard is not defective? Try another keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. Try replace caps lock with other key:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
XKB`OPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

See here for more ideas: https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux#ubuntu-2104